# What's the difference between different method declarations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have seen developers using different ways to declare/define functions in js,

like:

```
// 1
createview:function()
{

}

// 2.
var createview=function()
{
}

// 3.
function createview()
{
}
```

While 2nd and 3rd are function expression and declaration respectively, what's with the 1st usage?

Comment: the first case is used when you want to assign function as property of object

Comment: C'mon guys. This is not duplicate. Without other object notation the answer should be `label` in Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme That's not correct. An anonymous function cannot be used as a statement (and it would serve no purpose if it could). Pretty sure OP just left the relevant details out.

Answer (score 0):

Its an object and used for example in the revealing module pattern.

```
var module = (function() {

  var stuff = function() { return 'stuff'; };

  return {

    stuff: stuff

  }

}());
```

Now you have a name spaced closure.

```
module.stuff() //--> returns 'stuff'
```